# XSD date format overriding

Tags: xml, xsd

I am defining an XSD. I need to define an element which takes date in format yyyymmdd. How can I define a restriction in XSD to only accept this format?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could always define it as a restricted simple type based on a string, restricted by a regular expression:

```
<xs:simpleType name="FormattedDateType">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:pattern value="\d{8}"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

If you want to get really smart, you can tweak the regular expression to be even more of a match for a date (e.g. contains the info that month can only be 01 - 12 and so forth):

```
<xs:simpleType name="FormattedDateType">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:pattern value="\d{4}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Marc

Comment: Marc I knew this expression but I thought its not the right way. I thought I need to extend xs:date and override the format.

Comment: Quite honestly, I never thought of restricting xs:date or xs:dateTime, and setting a pattern - not sure if it'll work - give it a try!

Comment: You can't extend a simple type (not via xs:extension) and you can't restrict something to be not valid as part of the base. A 'yyyymmdd' formatted date is not a valid xs:date (it requires the 'yyyy-mm-dd' format) so you need something like marc_s' solution

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem though. You can just use an adapter to get the actual stringly-typed date value in your app.

Answer (score -2):

If you want the format of MM/DD/YYYY in xml then this code can help you for this format

```
<xs:element name="StartDate">
   <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:pattern value="\d{2}[/]\d{2}[/]\d{4}"/>
     <xs:length value="10"/>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: <xs:simpleType name="dateVal">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:pattern value="^([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([2][01]|[1][6-9])\d{2}(\s([0-1]\d|[2][0-3])(\:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$"></xs:pattern>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>

Comment: @SamirVasani, I didn't think XML schemas supported anchor elements like ^ and $ when pattern matching. Have you tested your suggestion?

Comment: Careful when using this expression since it allows invalid dates like 98/76/4321