# Why isn't my XML date accepting dates in YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: t-sql, xsd

I don't understand why the xsd rule I have created for a date is not working.
The rule is: `<xs:element name="scan_date" type="xs:date" />`
which, accoring to [XML Schema Date on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp) is specified in the following form "YYYY-MM-DD", yet when the XML Parser in SQL encounters `<scan_date>2006-12-15</scan_date>` it fails because it doesn't accept the date as valid, yet if I swap the 12 and 15 round it does.

Comment: Could you construct and post a short but complete script that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Sounds to me like your problem is rather SQL server locale setting expecting a `YYYY-DD-MM` date format.

Comment: @Filburt - I _think_ you're probably right. The user account for SQL is using English rather than British English for it's default language. Unfortunately I can't change the locale (changing it would break existing functionality) and I can't change the data (that's provided from a 3rd party). All I can do is work with the xsd, do you know if there's a way to supply date format information?

Comment: @Simon The only way I can think of is changing the data type from `xs:date` to a regex equivalent.

Comment: @Filburt - the alternative is xs:string I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution using `xs:string` and a regex restriction:

```
<xs:element name="scan_date" type="dateType"/>

<xs:simpleType name="dateType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="\d{4}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

... adopted from [XSD date format overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047958/xsd-date-format-overriding)