# How do I change for each statement to display date of birth in xml result?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a xml document that I am using for each to loop through parties. I need to get `PartyID` and `DateOfBirth`. I am getting `PartyID`, but `DateOfBirth` is showing `0001-01-01T00:00:00`.

**XML Document**

```xml
<Integration>
    <Case>
        <CaseEvent Date="06/14/2010" ID="252945068">
            <PartyID>9919636</PartyID>
        </CaseEvent>
        <CaseParty ID="9919636">
            <DateOfBirth>04/27/1910</DateOfBirth>
        </CaseParty>
    </Case>
    <IntegrationConditions>
        <IntegrationCondition Word="TAWQ" Description="Inserts">
            <NotificationEvent notificationType="TAWQ" elementKey="252945068">InsertSomething</NotificationEvent>
        </IntegrationCondition>
    </IntegrationConditions>
</Integration>
```

**Expected result**

```xml
<InsertPWBRorAOS xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">
    <RelatedParties>
        <CaseParty>
            <DateOfBirth>04/27/1910</DateOfBirth>
            <PartyId>9919636</PartyId>
        </CaseParty>
    </RelatedParties>
</InsertPWBRorAOS>
```

**Actual result**

```xml
<InsertPWBRorAOS xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">
    <RelatedParties>
        <CaseParty>
            <DateOfBirth>0001-01-01T00:00:00</DateOfBirth>
            <PartyId>9919636</PartyId>
        </CaseParty>
    </RelatedParties>
</InsertPWBRorAOS>
```

**My VB.NET code**

```vb
Public Shared Sub ProcessInsertPWBRorAOS(ByRef aobjXmlInputDoc As System.Xml.XmlDocument, ByVal aobjxmlNotificationEventNode As XmlNode)
    Dim objInsertPWBRorAOS As MMGService.InsertPWBRorAOS = New MMGService.InsertPWBRorAOS
    Dim objCaseParty As MMGService.CaseParty
    Dim objxmlEventPartyIDNode As XmlNode
    Dim strEventId As String

    strEventId = aobjxmlNotificationEventNode.SelectSingleNode("@elementKey").InnerText
    objCaseParty = New MMGService.CaseParty()

    'Loop through all PartyIDNodes in CaseEvent with ID equal to NotificationEvent's elementKey 
    For Each objxmlEventPartyIDNode In aobjXmlInputDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Case/CaseEvent[@ID=" + strEventId + "]/PartyID")
        strPartyID = objxmlEventPartyIDNode.InnerText
        objCaseParty.PartyId = strPartyID
        'DateofBirth
        objCaseParty.DateOfBirth = dtmDateOfBirth
        objInsertPWBRorAOS.RelatedParties(i) = objCaseParty
        i += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You add an undefined variable `dtmDateOfBirth`.. Perhaps use something like `dtmDateOfBirth = aobjXmlInputDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Case/CaseParty[@ID=" + strPartyID + "]/DateOfBirth").InnerText`

Comment: The objCaseParty object have DateOfBirth and other elements. This is why I used the object to get the PartyID

Comment: I know, but where do you set the value for `dtmDateOfBirth`? As your code is now, it is simply an undefined variable.

Comment: Oh I now get it. Thanks. I will add it as you suggested. If this work then I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this unanswered question of yours. It's almost a year old. Based on the comments so far, the question still seems to be open. So I would like to provide you with an answer, hoping that it can still be useful for you.

It is not entirely clear to me what the actual issue is. There might be two issues with your date of birth value in your result.

1. The date does not seem to be set; it is set to January 1, 0001. That is the minimum value of a `Date` (`System.DateTime`) variable and also the initial value of class member variables of that data type when they are not explicitly initialized.
2. The formatting of the date value is different (compared to the "Expected result" section).

I will address both potential issues below.

**Regarding point 1:**

The field `objCaseParty.DateOfBirth` is set to the value of variable `dtmDateOfBirth`. So it seems that this `dtmDateOfBirth` variable is not set/initialized correctly as well. I would suggest to search your code for all references to the `dtmDateOfBirth` variable. Perhaps you forgot to set its value somewhere, or you want to additionally check if the date of birth is not yet set (and abort execution and warn the user when necessary).

**Regarding point 2:**

Normally, any fields of type `Date` will be stored/serialized in XML using the format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`.

If you only want to drop the time part, you could use/modify the XML Schema Definition (XSD) and explicitly include/change the type of the field to `xs:date`. (Eventually, the XSD will probably contain a line similar to something like 
`<xs:element name="DateOfBirth" type="xs:date"/>`.) With this change, the date will be stored in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

If you want the date values to be stored explicitly in the format `MM/dd/yyyy`, I see no other way than to store/serialize it as a string value. It will require some additional programming, but there are several answers already available on StackOverflow that will get you on your way with this, like:

- [John Saunders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76337)' [answer to question "Can you specify format for XmlSerialization of a datetime?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1118855/4174789)
- [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302)' [answer to question "XSD date format overriding"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1048049/4174789)

**Note regarding your For Each loop:**

Inside your For Each loop, you use an iteration variable `i`. This variable is being incremented within the For Each loop, but it is not declared with an initial value before the loop starts. I guess you are missing a line like `Dim i As Integer = 0`.